# Can I express the relation between the parameter from statutory tax rate and effective tax function(GS,1994) as equation?

Tags: taxation

Can I get the equation which express the relation between the parameters of statutory income tax and those of the effective tax function(by using data from the previous tax reform, counter factual analysis or something)? Can such an equation be used to analyze future changes in the tax system?

I have effective income tax function from Gouveia&Strauss(1994). I want to find an intuitive answer or a hint about the research results that exist.